# When should we use createTempView in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Assume I am loading data using:

```
df = spark.read("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("path/to/csv")
```

Then why I need to run: `df.createTempView("temp_df")` ? If its because I need to be able to run `sql` queries, then can't I do that using: `df.selectExpr("sql exp...")`?

I am aware that `df.createTempView("temp_df")` will create a table which I can run `sql` expressions against, in a Spark session. Having said that, does that mean that the created table is distributed on the worker nodes?

The reason I'm asking is because I would like to know if the csv file is being loaded to the driver program and not the worker nodes immediately.

Second, can I have a dataframe on the worker nodes? If yes, then will `spark.catalog.listTables()` give me any information about this dataframe?

Finally, how can I check where is my data stored at any point of time?Being it dataframe or sql tables?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Spark doesn't actually transfer the data between driver and/or worker nodes. It all relies on having the data in a shared storage layer. So for example when you use createTempView, then the view will be stored in your Hive warehouse, located on something like HDFS. Every other node in the cluster can access that same file from the shared storage.